# Block Diagram featuring bias and skip connection

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tikz-arrows

I am trying to implement the following Block Diagram which illustrates some Neural Network with bias and skip connection:

[image]

My mediocre attempt is based on https://tikz.net/skip-connection/.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning, calc, decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

  \node[fill=yellow!50] (l1) {$(I + \alpha \lambda A^{H}A)^{-1}$};
  \node[fill=teal!50, right=of l1] (l2) {H};
  \node[right=of l2, font=\Large, inner sep=0, ] (add) {$\oplus$};
  \node[blue!50!black, right=of add, label={}] (act2) {$x_{k+1}$};

  \draw[->] (l1) -- (l2);
  \draw[<-] (l1) -- ++(-2,0) node[below, pos=0.8] {$x_k$};
  \draw[->] (l2) -- (act2) node[above, pos=0.8] {};
  \draw[->] ($(l1)-(1.5,0)$) to[out=90, in=90] node[below=1ex, midway, align=center] {} node[above, midway] {$1 - \alpha$} (add);


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: As you know, the best way is to show your \draw attempts, starting at \documentclass, ending at \end{document}.

Comment: That looks not too bad :) Hint: name the input (in) i.e. remember that coordinate. Then do: \draw[->] (in) -| (l2); so Tikz can fold that line for you (see manual for details). Also add align=center to the options of (l2) AND change text to {H\\CNN}, i.e. write a multiline.

Comment: {H\\CNN} does not work for some reason. Either way, I must admit that I could definitely get \oplus in the middle and then the arrows to it. But the bifurcation I just don't know

Comment: For `\\\\ ` you need a multiline node. Adding `align=center` (or whatever alignment you prefer) will do that. As @MS-SPO said already, I just realised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the hints alone did not suffice. So let's have a closer look.

BTW, this is just another example that copying is only part of the equation: the other, more important one is learning. So I highly suggest to read, try and review [the tutorials in the pgfmanual](https://tikz.dev/) several times. Most you need here is already shown there.

For the process of creating such a diagram, these are the steps:

- 1. place all required nodes with some initial text; ignore labels
- 2. draw connections; let them be imperfect, e.g. without meandering for now
- 3. introduce and use your styles
- 4. introduce `|-` or `-|` as needed; add some more nodes to the paths as labels
- 5. review and apply small corrections; here I put a demo for an alternative at  the input

[image: result]

###### About #1

I decided to use absolut coordinates, as relative positioning could be done here, but is kind of not-needed here. See also [the matrix approach](https://tikz.dev/tutorial-chains#sec-5.4.1) in the tutorial.

Turned out I don't need any of these libraries `\usetikzlibrary{positioning, calc, decorations.pathreplacing};` but I left them here to have the two approaches compared in one compile.

###### Example for #2

Just focus on connecting the right nodes, even criss-crossing without any meandering. Care for that later. So start with

```
    \draw[->] (in1) -- (l1);
```

instead of the final (see the [chapter end right before this link](https://tikz.dev/tutorial#sec-2.22) about |-)

```
    \draw[->] (in1) |- (l1);
```

Instead of fighting battles already here it's often better to watch the overall diagram grow (and taking some (mental) notes for later improvements).

###### Example for #2 -> #3

After basic absolute placement this line

```
    \node (l1)  at (2,-1) {$H$};
```

becomes

```
    \node[blkg] (l1)    at (2,-1) {$H$\\CNN};
```

because its style `blkg` now contains all formatting needed (color, multiline, width), while keeping code clean:

```
blkg/.style={fill=green!30!gray!30,align=center,minimum width=15mm},
```

###### Example for #4

Ok, the diagram is already quite good at this stage, so let's have a look at the labels needed. There are many ways to put them. Here I chose inserting an additional node into the path, like so:

What started out as just an connecting arrow

```
    \draw[->] (in1) -- (add);
```

now has an other node added (notice the missing `\`), just put above

```
    \draw[->] (in1) -- node[above] {$1 - \alpha$} (add);
```

Turns out after compile, this already looks nice enough to me. You can fine-tune where the node is displayed in relative units along said path, either `verbally` or by using `pos`, see ["Adding text"](https://tikz.dev/tutorial#sec-2.21):

```
    \draw[->] (l1) -| node[right, near end] {$\alpha$} (add);
    
    \draw[->] (in2) -- node[right,pos=.3] {$\alpha \times \lambda$} (add);
```

###### Demo #5

Just in case you don't like

```
    \draw[->] (in1) |- (l1);
```

you could also introduce an additional point in the path and meander like this:

```
    \draw[->,red,thick] (in1) -- +(0.6,0) |- (l1.160);
```

where the strange node coordinate `(l1.160)` just tells where to anchor the line (think of a polar coordinate).

#### Code

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning, calc, decorations.pathreplacing}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}% ~~~ only this one needed for "After"

\begin{document}

%After:
 \begin{tikzpicture}[% ~~~ 3. define (and use) your styles ~~~~
    >=Stealth,%     changing the arrow tips
    blkg/.style={fill=green!30!gray!30,align=center,minimum width=15mm},
    blky/.style={fill=yellow!50,align=center,inner sep=2mm},
    add/.style={font=\Large, inner sep=0},
 ]
    % ~~~ 1. blocks ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \node       (in1)   at (0, 0) {$x_k$};
    \node[blkg] (l1)    at (2,-1) {$H$\\CNN};
    \node[add]  (add)   at (4, 0) {$\oplus$};
    \node       (in2)   at (4, 2) {$A^{H_b}$};
    \node[blky] (l2)    at (6.5, 0) {$(I + \alpha \lambda A^{H}A)^{-1}$\\
                                   DC using CG};
    \node       (out)   at (9, 0) {$x_{k+1}$};
    
    % ~~~ 2. connections ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    % ~~~ 4. add some nodes to the paths for the labels ~~~~~~~~~
    \draw[->] (in1) -- node[above] {$1 - \alpha$} (add);
    \draw[->] (add) -- (l2);
    \draw[->] (l2) -- (out);

    \draw[->] (in1) |- (l1);
    \draw[->] (l1) -| node[right, near end] {$\alpha$} (add);
    
    \draw[->] (in2) -- node[right,pos=.3] {$\alpha \times \lambda$} (add);
    
    % ~~~ 5. just to demonstrate it ~~~~
    \draw[->,red,thick] (in1) -- +(0.6,0) |- (l1.160);
 \end{tikzpicture}


%Before:
\begin{tikzpicture}

  \node[fill=yellow!50] (l1) {$(I + \alpha \lambda A^{H}A)^{-1}$};
  \node[fill=teal!50, right=of l1] (l2) {H};
  \node[right=of l2, font=\Large, inner sep=0, ] (add) {$\oplus$};
  \node[blue!50!black, right=of add, label={}] (act2) {$x_{k+1}$};

  \draw[->] (l1) -- (l2);
  \draw[<-] (l1) -- ++(-2,0) node[below, pos=0.8] {$x_k$};
  \draw[->] (l2) -- (act2) node[above, pos=0.8] {};
  \draw[->] ($(l1)-(1.5,0)$) to[out=90, in=90] node[below=1ex, midway, align=center] {} node[above, midway] {$1 - \alpha$} (add);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```